# Relation between divergence of unit normal and radius of curvature

Tags: tensor-calculus, vector-fields

I don't understand how does the divergence of a unit normal vector to a curve at a point gives the local radius of curvature. For simplicity consider a 2-D curve.
$$\nabla.n=\frac{1}{R}$$
I want to understand the mathematical proof for the expression and also some physical intuition to understand why is this true.

Comment: This is a great question. I would recommend you the book Tristan Needhams Visual Differential Geomtry.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.

Comment: Was something not clear in my answer?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Could you provide a link to the div.X formula you began your derivation with? Also that example of circle is exactly what I first did myself when I came across the relation to check whether the relation holds true. Although it did but I was not satisfied with the outcome so I wanted some real mathematical proof of the theorem. I just can't find it anywhere on internet. It would be really helpful if you could share the derivation of that formula.

Comment: If you see the linked post that I had put to MSE, I say the page number of Tristan Needham's book and my attempt at filling in the gaps of Needham's proof. Also, there is a linked math overflow post which I had put where it is found that it is a simplified case of a much general formula @Apoorv Mishra

Comment: Also Pavel Grinfeld's book, in that book he actually gets rid of this div, grad curl notation because it's mostly somewhat of a handicap when dealing with higher order tensor quantites. But, I am sure in some page this formula exists as a simplification of the tensor formula. He actually has a youtube course on tensor calculus which I myself found helpful. You can check that out for more details

Comment: Ok yeah I put a simple geometric proof using definition of divergence for this. Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

To give you feel of what is involved consider the diagram shown below.

[image]
For small angle $d \theta$, $n=n'=1 \Rightarrow dn = n\,d\theta=d\theta$ and $R=R' \Rightarrow dR = R\,d\theta$

Thus $\frac {dn}{dR} = \frac 1R$.

Comment: Thanks for responding. It does provide some intuition but I'm still a bit confused. You said that n=n'=1 but n is a vector so instead ¦n¦ =1 and therefore we will get the final expression in terms of modulus of n which is not a vector. So is there a way to express this whole thing in Cartesian coordinates? Or could you provide some link to mathematical derivation of this?

Comment: I've searched a lot on internet but can't find anything that gives it's derivation.

Comment: @ApoorvMishra  Where did you come across the relationship?

Comment: I was watching a lecture on thin film dynamics in Fluid Mechanics, and in it, to derive an equation, this relation is used to substitute the radius of curvature in terms of divergence of unit surface normal vector. Link is below.

Comment: https://youtu.be/OVUIDtzVsek   See at 12:50

Answer (score 1):

I remember a Tensor calculus component proof in **Pavel Grinfeld's** book but a much more I've attempted at a simpler Geometric explanation of the formula using definition of divergence via integral in this [post of MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4404243/proving-geometric-definition-of-divergence-of-vector-field-as-given-by-tristan-n) adapted from Tristan Needham's book. You may also see linked post to Math Overflow for more detailed discussion.

Anyhow, given the formula:

> $$ \nabla \cdot X = \partial_s |X| + \kappa_p |X|$$

If we have unit normal to curve $\hat{n}$ , then the first term of RHS is zero as unit normal doesn't change length. Also, the second term is just $\kappa_p$ i.e: curvature of the curve we are considering. Hence, we can write:

$$ \nabla \cdot n= \kappa_p $$

A more detailed derivation and conditions for extending this result into higher dimensions is in linked.

---

Here is an example calculation using this formula: We have a circle of radius $r$: $x^2 +y^2 = r^2$, one can find it's unit normal as $\frac{<x,y>}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}$. Plugging this into formula we have:

$$ \nabla \cdot \left[ \frac{<x,y>}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}\right] =  \kappa_p (1)$$

The left side, it is equivalent to taking divergence of the unit radial vector $\hat{r}$. By computing divergence in polar:

$$ \nabla \cdot \left[ \frac{<x,y>}{\sqrt{x^2 +y^2}}\right]=\nabla \cdot (1 \hat{r}) = \frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial }{\partial r} ( 1 \cdot r) = \frac{1}{r}$$

So, $\kappa_p = \frac{1}{r}$ which is what we need.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really bad at drawing but have a look at this:

[image]
The bottom part can be seen as a segment of the original surface $S_o$ all points on it flow according to the surface normal, so after some time $t$ they from the top face. If we were to integrate the surface normal over this this cube and divide it by it's volume, we have the definition of divergence:

$$ \lim_{dV \to 0} \frac{\oint n \cdot dS}{dV} = \nabla \cdot n$$

We need to work out LHS, so here $dV$ we can take to be the volume increase of the oscullating sphere times some angle propotionality constant $\kappa$. If the radius of osculating sphere is given as $\kappa d(\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3)$,.  For the actual surface integral, it is easy to see that only the top most and bottom most face contribute to it (from prespective we see it in photo). By how much? Well by surface area of patch at $S_{t+dt} $ and negative of that of $S_t$. This would be $ d(4 \pi r^2) \kappa$ where $\kappa$ is the same angle propotionality factor. We have:

$$  \lim_{ dV \to 0} \frac{\oint n \cdot dS}{dV} = \frac{d( 4 \pi r^2) \kappa}{ d( \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3) \kappa} = \frac{1}{r} = \nabla \cdot n$$

Comment: Btw the $\kapppa $ being equal can be thought of as how when we want to find a circumfrence / area of a sector of a circle, we just take the regular formula and multiply by $ \frac{\theta}{ 2 \pi}$